# Storing completed payment information from the new 'Pay link or button' PayPal integration

Tags: paypal

In my PayPal (merchant) [sandbox site](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/buttons), I've generated the code to integrate PayPal buttons on my website:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=myClientId&components=hosted-buttons&disable-funding=venmo&currency=EUR"></script>
<div id="paypal-container-foobar"></div>
<script>
  paypal.HostedButtons({
    hostedButtonId: "MYHOSTEDBUTTONSID",
  }).render("#paypal-container-foobar")
</script>
```

When I click "PayPal" the popup is shown. I can pay the amount with my customer sandbox account. A transaction is created, but I cannot find any resource or documentation on how to check that the payment was completed to communicate with my server and store data about the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The "Pay link or button" solution from [www.paypal.com/buttons](http://www.paypal.com/buttons) is intended for simple HTML pages—*not* servers with a backend that will store data.

To record completed (captured) payments with a backend, integrate [standard checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) instead and use the immediate API response of success/failure before propagating the result to the client side JS (which then shows a thank you or error message)